# How to draw arc using svg.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

Using [svg.js](http://www.svgjs.com/) I would like to draw path with arc:

```
M75,0 L75,118.85 A30,30 0 0 0 640,660.15 L568.5690264688633,781.8607965826662
```

I have tried everything (gaps, commas,...) but not success. Still getting error:

`Error: Problem parsing d="M 50 0 L 50 108.8499984741211 A      660.3822631835938 199.75233459472656 L 631.133056640625 133.80345153808594"`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What did you actually write? The following worked for me: `var draw = SVG('drawing').size(800, 800).path("M75,0 L75,118.85 A30,30 0 0 0 640,660.15 L568.5690264688633,781.8607965826662 ").attr({ stroke: '#000', fill: 'none' });`

Comment: I wrote `$svg.path("M75,0 L75,118.85 A30,30 0 0 0 710.3045697572263,209.82594606724422 L728.8662409116116,189.78229476017066")`. But the output si `M 75 0 L 75 118.8499984741211 A      710.3045654296875 209.82594299316406 L 728.8662109375 189.78228759765625`

Comment: I've tried to use your code a got the same as mine :( Which version are you using?

Comment: Strange. I just followed your link and downloaded it from there.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Have you downloaded devel or production version?

Comment: So I've downloaded the latest version and it's working now :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin https://github.com/otm/svg.path.js which provides a easier interface to create paths. With the plugin you can for instance write write:

```
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(800, 800);
var path draw.path().M(10, 10).L(20, 20)
```

Here are some examples for the plugin: http://otm.github.io/svg.path.js/

There is also a new feature in svg.js called path array:

https://github.com/wout/svg.js#svgpatharray

Comment: For everyone who wants to draw an arc along a circle, you will find an answer here: https://github.com/otm/svg.path.js/issues/21